# Unable to configure a simple IEC connector with an illuminated switch

Tags: connector

I have [this](http://www.bulgin.com/vertical-power-entry-module-bzv49-bzv50-series-c20-cold-condition-inlet-px0598-group.html) IEC connector with an illuminated single-pole switch.

Here is how it looks like from back side:
[image]

As you see above the earth, line and the neutral are mentioned. But for the switch side there is no marks so I marked them as A B and C.

Here is the catalog for this type of connectors:
http://www.bulgin.com/media/bulgin/data/Power%20Entry%20Modules.pdf

If you go to page 277 you find this model named as **C20 IEC Inlet**.

I cannot see any kind of information how line and neutral will be wired to the illuminated switch. Is there a standard or how can I figure this out?

**Edit:**

Let's say I would know which pin is 1 2 and 3.

There can be two ways to wire this:

Config 1

[image]

or

Config 2

[image]

Dashed gray line is when the switch is OFF. I think the pin 2 is the fixed pin.

But which configuration is better than the other one?

Btw I only tried Config 1 and the switch makes arc like sound when one turns it on.

Comment: How you connect this switch and the connector is totally up to you – why should the manufacturer tell you how to build whatever you're building with their plug and switch?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you mean A=line B=C=neutral or A=B=line C=neutral also okay? There are many combinations man. (?) I didnt get it

Comment: Pop the switch out of the holder, the circuit diagram is on the side, not the bottom.

Comment: @RonBeyer I did what you say and there is no diagram on sides of it when I pop it up from the frame. There is only some rated values but no diagram at all. Not even pin numbers 1 2 3 are mentioned.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Please attach the technical characteristics of the load.

Comment: Load is just a power supply supplying some amplifiers. In my pic M is juts a representative load. Dont get stuck on it. There is no motor or inductive load.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look a page 2 of that document and you’ll see this:
[image]
This says to me that you want to connect the hot input to pin 1, your load to pin 2 and neutral to pin 3 to complete the circuit for the light.

Now as for which pins are 1, 2 and 3, that’s not clear but take and ohmmeter and check to see which pins open and close with the switch: those are 1 and 2. If the light stays on even with the switch open, you have 1 and 2 switched - easy to fix.

Comment: Please see my edit. I would like to have your comment

Answer (score 0):

That datasheet is difficult to interpret.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8b0tZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Switch schematic.*

Given the problem I would approach it as follows:

Using a continuity tester identify the switch contacts. They will go between over-range and zero when opened and closed. The third contact is neutral.

[image]

*Figure 2. Possible wiring. Colour codes are European.*

- If 'C' is the neutral then wire it up as shown.
- Power up and test the switch. The power indicator should go from off to on with the switch.
- If the indicator remains on with the switch then swap the two non-neutral wires on the switch.

Comment: Thanks and did you see my Edit? What do you think of that?

Comment: I saw your edit and reckoned you needed some help with electrical schematic symbols. I couldn't make much sense of it. There's a schematic tool built into the editor toolbar. It uses standard symbols.

Comment: Alright let me ask you this way then. Lets focus on your picture(the second one). If the wire LOAD goes to A,and Line L goes to B, would that be still okay?

Comment: If it works it's fine. The very important thing is that you don't short out L and N when the switch contacts close.